# Equalize number of columns and rows number with different raster data which was taken from different sources

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, cell-size

I am interested in creating a flood map using machine learning methods. I need the same number of columns and rows for each raster data or layer. However, although I used the same boundaries for cutting raster datasets, I have a different number of columns and rows. By the way, cell sizes are the same for all data.

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.7.1 When ı using the "resampling" tool, cell sizes become equal with other data, columns and rows do not change significantly

Comment: Take a look at clipping and snap to raster options in addition to resampling. The combination can help you ensure same exact dimensions.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Using the Processing extent settings does not solve the problem.  I have been trying with ArcMap and then used R (crop() and resample() ) but that does not solve the problem neither.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS 10.8:

- Use Extract by Mask;
- Input Raster: the raster layer with the wrong # of columns and rows;
- Input Raster or Feature Mask Data: the layer with the correct # of columns and rows;
  Output Raster: your choice;
- Click Environment tab;
- Click Processing Extent, and browse to the layer with the correct # of columns and rows;
- Snap Raster should be the same layer (the correct layer);
- Click OK;
- Check the layer property--> Source