# Using extract by mask in ArcGIS Pro about rows and columns

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, pixel

I want to clip a precipitation raster to fit my study area. I have a standard raster of my study area whose rows and columns are 1510 and 1656.

However, when I use "extract by mask" tool, the results are different between ArcGIS Pro2.8.3 and ArcMap 10.3.

The rows and columns of the result in ArcGIS Pro 2.8.3 are 1511 and 1657 while the rows and columns of the result in ArcMap 10.3 are 1510 and 1656.

The result of ArcMap10.3 is correct so why does ArcGIS Pro have this problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: ArcPro could be being more precise, i.e., there could be 2 tiny slivers under the mask shape that it is choosing to include. Look up how to set geoprocessing environment parameters.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370934/equalize-number-of-columns-and-rows-number-with-different-raster-data-which-was This should help.